# Sync specific files to the Steam Cloud

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

Is it possible to sync specific files (user input settings, progress) of a game that supports Steam Cloud to the Steam Cloud?

For instance: during the week I play on a GTX 960M and during the weekends on a GTX 970. Every time I switch, I've to change my graphics settings (not manually but via NVIDIA GeForce Experience).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sync to steam cloud is handled by the game. You have no influence on what is synced and what not, unless you can configure it in the game (haven't seen this yet though).

What you CAN do: If you know which files are responsible for these settings you can backup them to another location and copy them back when you need them changed. You can do this with a small script on doubleclick.

Comment: That is indeed an option, but Steam will still point out that your local files differ from your cloud files. This is of course just a single dialog box. But if it becomes a habit of always considering the local files as the correct files in case of the 'correct' graphics settings, this can result in a disaster if it isn't just for the graphics files.